# Direct Update does not apply update after unpacking MF8.0

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

After migrating from MF7.1 to MF8.0, we used cordova WKWebView plugin for ios. This broke the direct update. Even after installing `wkwebview-engine-localhost` plugin referred from this link, [IBM Knowledge Center: Known limitations](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_known_limitations.html), the direct update is still broken (updates are not applied even after unpacking). The latest iFix has also been applied. Is there any other steps for the workaround?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to the following recently-opened bug in WKWebView: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12340

Until it is resolved it seems this is a dead end.
One work around you can do is to install a previous build of WKWebView which may work, and then the solution to use `wkwebview-engine-localhost` with that previous build of WKWebView will allow you to continue working with this web view.

Comment: The linked issue's workaround is to install urijs `npm install urijs` before adding the plugin. Both WKWebView and local webserver plugin works fine but not with Direct Update.